# False integral sum interchange theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

one of my teachers gave us the following theorem :

> Let $(f_n)_n$ be a sequence of functions defined over $D\subset \mathbb{R}$ with range in $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. If $\displaystyle \left\vert\int_Ddx\right\vert <+\infty$ and $ \sum f_n $ converges uniformly over $D$, then $\displaystyle \int_D \left(\sum f_n \right)dx = \sum \Bigl(\int_D f_n dx\Bigr) $.

I tend to believe this is false, because already with interchanging sum and limit, if the domain $ D $ is not compact, then we can't always interchange them (for example with $\displaystyle I_n = \int_0^1 \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^n}}dt$).

I know that one of the main theorem to apply interchange is the Fubini theorem, in which the main hypothesis would translate here into $\displaystyle \iint_{D\times\mathbb{N}} \vert f_n\vert\ d(\lambda \otimes \mu) $, with . But to me this would be the absolute convergence of the series and not its uniform convergence.

Any insight ?

Comment: In your example what do you claim is the limit: $$\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^n}}$$For $t\in(0,1)$?

Comment: It is not too hard to show that: $$\sum_{n\ge1}\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^n}}\,\mathrm{d}t=+\infty$$But I’m curious about your counterexample.

Comment: Why does $\int f_n$ exist under the given hypothesis?

Comment: Maybe i poorly chose my word. $I_n$ is a counterexample when interchanging limit and integral, so i thought if one would find a finite sum which adds up to $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^n}}$, then the limit-integral interchange question can we reworded into a sum-integral interchange.

Comment: If $D$ is a closed interval and the $f_n$'s are Riemann integrable, the result is true. This is a standard result, see for example Apostol, T. Mathematical Analysis, 2nd edition, Addison-Wesley, 1974, pp. 225-226.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$The Fubini theorems are nuanced and there are variations such as the Tonelli theorem where finite convergence is not required, in some instances. Really the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem is what you are looking for here; uniform convergence of the series implies that eventually we can bound by an integrable function, and then the interchange is justified. For the Riemann integral it is also known that uniform convergence is sufficient for sum-integral exchange over a compact interval, but more care is sometimes needed to do this on the infinite intervals.

Regardless, your counterexample is not a counter example:

> $$\begin{align}\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^n}}\d t&=\frac{1}{n}\int_0^1\frac{u^{(1/n)-1}}{\sqrt{1-u}}\d u\\&=\frac{1}{n}\mathcal{B}(1/n,1/2)\\&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{n}\frac{\Gamma(1/n)}{\Gamma(1/n+1/2)}\\&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma(1/n+1/2)}\Gamma(1+1/n)\\&\to1\\&=\int_0^1\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^n}}\d t\end{align}$$

The limit-integral interchange is valid.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for Fubini's theorem to check the validity  the statement in the OP.

- If $D$ is a closed interval and the $f_n$'s are Riemann integrable, the result is true. This is a standard result, see for example Apostol, T. Mathematical Analysis, 2nd edition, Addison-Wesley, 1974, pp. 225-226.
- If $D$ is a measurable set of finite measure, and the  $f_n$'s are Lebesgue integrable the result holds. Indeed,  set $s_n=\sum^n_{j=1}f_j$ and $s=\sum_nf_n$. By hypothesis, there is $N>0$ such that $\|s-s_n\|_u<1$ for all $n\geq N$. Hence $|s(x)|\leq 1+|s_N(x)|$ for all $x\in D$. This implies that $s$ is Lebesgue integrable in $D$ (here the assumption  $|D|<\infty$ is used). On the other hand, $|s_n(x)|\leq 1+|s(x)|$ for all $n\geq N$ and $x\in D$. The conclusion the follows b y dominated convergence (here the assumption  $|D|<\infty$ is used).
- If the assumption $|D|<\infty$ is removed (here we deal with Lebesgue integral), then the statement may not hold. Here is a counter example. Consider $D=[0,\infty)$ and define $s_n=\frac{1}{2n}\mathbb{1}_{[0,2n]}$. Notice that $s_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0=: s$ uniformly. However $\int s =0\neq 1=\int s_n$.

---

You example does not satisfies the conditions of the stament in the OP, for  the sequence $\phi_n(x)=(1-x^n)^{-1/2}$, $0\leq x<1$,  does not converge uniformly to $1$ (there is an issue  near $x=1$).

Since the $\phi_n$'s are unbounded over $[0,1)$, we consider the  Lebesgue integral (or Kurtsweil-Schwartz integration). $\phi_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}1$  pointwise a.s., and $0\leq \phi_n(x)\leq \phi_1(x)$. Dominated convergence allows you to switch the order of limit and integration.